# Referring Schema name from JSON document

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, everit

I'm validation my JSON document with JSON schema by java.
All JSON document structures will not be same. So, we decided to send the JSON document with schema version/name.
Is there any way to validate the JSON document by referring the schema name in same document.
JSON doc structure:

```
{
    "$schema-URL":"http://json-schema.org/custom-schema.json",
    "no": 1,
    "name": "Lampshade",
    "price": 0
}
```

Schema:

```
{
  "$ref": "URL/ref took from JSON file"
}
```

is this possible to validate dynamically or any other way?.
I'm new to JSON validation thing. Please suggest some solution.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `if`/`then` to select which schema to apply depending on the value of `$schema-URL`.

```json
{
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "$schema-URL": { "const": "https://yourdomain.com/custom-schema.json" }
        },
        "required": ["$schema-URL"]
      },
      "then": { "$ref": "https://yourdomain.com/custom-schema.json" }
    }
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "$schema-URL": { "const": "https://yourdomain.com/another-custom-schema.json" }
        },
        "required": ["$schema-URL"]
      },
      "then": { "$ref": "https://yourdomain.com/another-custom-schema.json" }
    }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to use `$ref` with a value from the data, so you end up with some duplication and a lot of verbosity. It says, if "$schema-URL" is `https://yourdomain.com/custom-schema.json`, then validate against `https://yourdomain.com/custom-schema.json`.